# Getting proper element height when browser is zoomed

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to get HTML element's height by using `.height()` method while browser is zoomed, the returned value is not valid.

**Example**:
My element is 35px height with 100% browser zoom, `.height()` method returns 35px (and it's ok).
But when browser zoom is set to 125%, element is now 36.25px height, and `.height()`method returns 36px, and not exact 36.25px.

Any ideas how to get proper value? Is this a bug, or..?

Comment: Please create running code showing problem and why you need a fraction of a pixel.

Comment: Note that sub-pixels generally don't make sense. You cannot color half a pixel, for instance. Your screen can only distinguish physical pixels.

Comment: `.height()` should still return 35, no matter what your zoom is, dependent of using `$('#mydiv').height()` and `document.getelementbyid('myDiv').style.height` (not sure whether those would ever act differently; anyone?)

It appears to return 35 no matter what in the latest Firefox.

Comment: @EthanJ. `height()` returns the computed height and can not be compared to `element.style.height` or jQuery equivalent `css('height')`.

Comment: I think you need to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers this talks about finding the pixel ratio which in turn is used to get the zoom level.